# Using DataTable from another form

Tags: vb.net, datatable, compact-framework, tableadapter

I have a function that picks some data in a DataTable and it returns a value. My DataTable is filled by a TableAdapter. So far all is working fine.
Problem appears after I have set this function as public. I tried to call it from another form and my DataTable seems to be Nothing. Why? How can I use it again?

Comment: Do you have a local copy with the same name?

Comment: No I don't. I used another form like a pop up  windows (as MessageBox) to request a choice from user. All Datatables are managed by the back window. For now I have fixed the issue with this kind of line:  If MyDataSet.MyDataTable.Select().Length = 0 Then Me.MyDataTableTableAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet.MyDataTable). It's working but not very smart.

Comment: I check the record count of the table in the dataset, like: MyDataSet.MyDataTable.rows.count

Comment: Have you ever checked out the LHC?

Comment: The Large Hadron Collider

Answer (score 0):

I have my answer, my base windows is not a singleton. The popup window doesn't exchange with the base window, it created a new window and this 2nd window hasn't been initialized.